# How to find at most 6 nearest neighbors in 3D space?

Tags: python, 3d, nearest-neighbor

I need to find at most 6 (depending on the node position) nearest neighbors for each point in 3D space. If you imagine cube 3x3x3, each corner will have 3 neighbors, each edge 4, each point near to the wall 5 and each point inside that cube will have 6 neighbors, but in general I need to find nearest neighbor from each side (left, right, top, bottom, front and back) if only exists.

I can achieve that by dividing space for each point and searching for the nearest point in each bucket. But below code is way too slow for larger data (it would take ~250 minutes for ~70k points).

Example data:

```py
points = [
    (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0, 0, 2),
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 1, 1),
    (0, 1, 2),
    (0, 2, 0),
    (0, 2, 1),
    (0, 2, 2),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (1, 0, 1),
    (1, 0, 2),
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 2),
    (1, 2, 0),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 2, 2),
    (2, 0, 0),
    (2, 0, 1),
    (2, 0, 2),
    (2, 1, 0),
    (2, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 0),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 2)
]
```

Grouping points:

```py
for i, (x1, y1, z1) in enumerate(points):
    f_xy = lambda x, y: (x - x1) + (y - y1)
    g_xy = lambda x, y: (x - x1) - (y - y1)
    f_xz = lambda x, z: (x - x1) + (z - z1)
    g_xz = lambda x, z: (x - x1) - (z - z1)
    f_yz = lambda y, z: (y - y1) + (z - z1)
    g_yz = lambda y, z: (y - y1) - (z - z1)

    groups = {'right': [], 'left': [], 'front': [], 'back': [], 'top': [], 'bottom': []}

    for j, (x2, y2, z2) in enumerate(points):
        if i != j:
            if f_xy(x2, y2) >= 0 and g_xy(x2, y2) >= 0 and f_xz(x2, z2) >= 0 and g_xz(x2, z2) >= 0: groups['right'].append((x2, y2, z2))
            if f_xy(x2, y2) <= 0 and g_xy(x2, y2) <= 0 and f_xz(x2, z2) <= 0 and g_xz(x2, z2) <= 0: groups['left'].append((x2, y2, z2))


            if f_xy(x2, y2) > 0 and g_xy(x2, y2) < 0 and f_yz(y2, z2) >= 0 and g_yz(y2, z2) >= 0: groups['front'].append((x2, y2, z2))
            if f_xy(x2, y2) < 0 and g_xy(x2, y2) > 0 and f_yz(y2, z2) <= 0 and g_yz(y2, z2) <= 0: groups['back'].append((x2, y2, z2))


            if f_xz(x2, z2) < 0 and g_xz(x2, z2) > 0 and f_yz(y2, z2) < 0 and g_yz(y2, z2) > 0: groups['bottom'].append((x2, y2, z2))
            if f_xz(x2, z2) > 0 and g_xz(x2, z2) < 0 and f_yz(y2, z2) > 0 and g_yz(y2, z2) < 0: groups['top'].append((x2, y2, z2))


    print(f'Vertex: {(x1, y1, z1)}')
    print(len(groups['right']) + len(groups['left']) + len(groups['front']) + len(groups['back']) + len(groups['bottom']) + len(groups['top']))
    print('Left', groups['left'])
    print('Right', groups['right'])
    print('Front', groups['front'])
    print('Back', groups['back'])
    print('Top', groups['top'])
    print('Bottom', groups['bottom'])
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
Vertex: (0, 0, 0)
26
Left []
Right [(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
Front [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
Back []
Top [(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 2)]
Bottom []


Vertex: (0, 0, 1)
26
Left []
Right [(1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
Front [(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
Back []
Top [(0, 0, 2)]
Bottom [(0, 0, 0)]


Vertex: (0, 0, 2)
26
Left []
Right [(1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
Front [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2)]
Back []
Top []
Bottom [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)]

...
```

I tried to use KDTrees, but if points are located unevenly it may return 6 neighbors from the left side.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you have all the points in the cube always? in wich dimension are you working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @UlisesBussi, no, points can have random coordinates. They represent fluid particles in some vessel (not always cube)

Comment: so you have a list of points in 3d and you want the nearest neibors, in your example take 6 neighbors  and seems that you're using "manhatan distance" to calc that (i.e. moving one dimension at time) this is for something particular?

Comment: why do you think that i use manhattan distance? Points I have are some fluid particles. They are stored as a list, but I want to convert it to a graph. Every particle should be connected to nearest particle on the left, right, front, back, top and bottom if only exists at least one in that direction, no matter how far it is.

Comment: you're using `d = (x-x1) + (y-y1)+(z-z1)`<- this is manhatan  distance

Comment: wouldn't be easyer calculate all distances between points and select nearest points?

Comment: ```f_xy = lambda x, y: (x - x1) + (y - y1)
g_xy = lambda x, y: (x - x1) - (y - y1)
f_xz = lambda x, z: (x - x1) + (z - z1)
g_xz = lambda x, z: (x - x1) - (z - z1)
f_yz = lambda y, z: (y - y1) + (z - z1)
g_yz = lambda y, z: (y - y1) - (z - z1)```

Those are plane equations that divide space in 6 pieces.

Comment: Okey, my bad, I think that's is easyer to use some math library to operate mathematically and then find nearest, i'm posting a solution, if it isn't what you want let me know

Comment: It is still too much time consuming and requires a lot of memory.

Comment: you have 70k points and you want to find nn for every point so you will have time expensive algoritms or memory expensive algorithms there's no magic tricks for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a way to solve the problem of finding nearest neighbors is using `numpy` to calculate distances between points, sorting and get indices. For this you will have to transform your list of points to a numpy array with `points=np.array(points)`. For the sake of this example i will create my own `points`.

```
#CREATE POINTS
import numpy as np
points = np.random.randn(100,3)
```

[image]

```
#Find distances and nearests:
#select target point to find nearest
target_point = points[10]
n_nearest = 6

#calc distance
distances = ((points-target_point)**2).sum(1)**0.5
#find nearest
nearest_p = points[np.argsort(distances)[1:1+n_nearest]]
```

[image]

For last create a function to find nearest for one point and measure time for that:

```
def find_n_nearest(points,target_point,n_nearest):
    distances = ((points-target_point)**2).sum(1)**0.5
    nearest_p = points[np.argsort(distances)[1:1+n_nearest]]
    return nearest_p

n = int(2e4)
p = np.random.randn(n,3)
n_nearest= 6


#measure time
import time

t0 = time.time()
for i,target_point in enumerate(p):
    if not i%1000:
        print(i)
    find_n_nearest(p,target_point,n_nearest)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

wich throws:

```
        82.79649305343628 seconds for 30k points (3e4)

        35.90334725379944 seconds for 20k
```

---

As I said in comments there's no magic way, it's a time consumption or a memory consumption problem, with 70k it's hard to caching distance values without overflow your memory fast (~2.4e9 floats if you use half a matrix to store values)

---

**EDIT**
For 70k (7e4 points) it took: 478.503 seconds

---

**EDIT 2**

added detect a point in every direction, then tested it with 70k points and took  594.5 seconds

```
def find_nearest_dir(points,target_point):
    distances = ((points-target_point)**2).sum(1)**0.5
    sides = [
                points[:,0] > target_point[0],#right
                points[:,0] < target_point[0],#left
                points[:,1] > target_point[1],#front
                points[:,1] < target_point[1],#back
                points[:,2] > target_point[2],#top
                points[:,2] < target_point[2],#bottom                
            ]
    nearest = []
    for s in sides:
        dif_filt = distances[s]
        poi_filt = points[s]
        if len(dif_filt):
            nearest.append(poi_filt[np.argmin(dif_filt)])
        else:
            nearest.append([])
    return nearest
    
    
n =int(7e4)
p = np.random.randn(n,3)
n_nearest= 6


#measure time
import time

t0 = time.time()
q=[]
for i,target_point in enumerate(p):
    if not i%1000:
        print(i)
    q = find_nearest_dir(p,target_point)
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this method doesn't include criterion about directions. If point has 10 points on the left side and 1 on right but not that close it will take 6 points from the left.

Comment: help me to understand you need the points to be one to every side (one left, one right, one up, one down, one front and one back?)

Comment: what about now?

Comment: Thank you for all answers, I really appreciate them, but with current solution there is a high chance that some points will be in many sides so the result wont be correct.

Comment: I modified latest version a bit and IT seems to work fine. Thank you for help!